# JMeter - How to obtain error rate per page on a specific timeframe

Tags: jmeter

I have been looking on the site and I don't see anything related to this topic, so I decided to ask.

Basically, I would like to know if there is a way to extract the error rate per page using a period of time. The reason is because we run a test in different stages, with different levels of throughput. Therefore, I am interested in obtain the degradation on page health. I already got the hits and response times. However, the error rate I don't see a way to get it.

If someone knows a way, please share!

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jp@gc - Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=HitsPerSecond) - listener. Just click on Errors check box to show only the failed requests which is the Error rate you are looking for!

For page level Error rate, you can [jp@gc - Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=TransactionsPerSecond)

[image]

Comment: That works for me. The Transaction per second will do the magic. I may need to do some parsing on Excel, but still works :). There is not a summary or agregate way to see it, isn't? //Maybe too much to ask for hehe.

Comment: Aggregate report will also show. Choose any listener you want. but ensure that you select the `Error` option.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

1. Response Codes Per Second chart available via [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

   [image: Error Codes - AppDEX]
2. Response Codes Per Second chart available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/)

   [image: Response Code per Second Plugins]
3. Use 3-rd party analysis solution like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

   [image: BM.Sense Timelines]